# Without installing SQL Server, .net application which inserts data can run on the machine?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Is there any way that without installing SQL Server on a machine, a .NET application which inserts and updates data can run on the machine?

Comment: Inserts and updates data where?  A client can insert and update data on a remote SQL Server without having SQL Server itself, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SQL Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033CFB76-5382-44FB-BC7E-B3C8174832E2) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (if you want the data stored locally).

Otherwise, you can connect to a centralised database server.

Comment: sir, i want that only mdf file is copied on the user pc and the .net application uses that file to insert data in it and retrieve from it. how to do it? i mean what would be the Connection String? and also, SqlConnection , SqlDataReader will be used or not?